# How to Sync Three or Multiple List Views in horizontal scroll view?

Tags: java, android, listview, horizontalscrollview

[image]

I have three list view one list view outside at the horizontal scroll view and another two list view in horizontal scroll view. When horizontal scroll I have show third list view specific position because I want some data fixed in scroll view. I have implemented, but one issue how to scroll all list view same time with smooth scroll, don't want to use scroll view. Please help me any one.

Comment: why shoud you have to make three listview? you can impliment this view in single listview

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Because i want to frozen view when horizontal scroll view reached specific position so i have use two list view in horizontal scroll view and out side list also frozen so i have use three list view.